# Check string for numbers

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a string contains a number, positive or negative.

```
getline(cin,line);

    istringstream sin(line);

    while (sin >> ws >> in){

        if(all_of(in.begin(), in.end(), ::isdigit){
        //do something with number
        }
```

Problem is, isdigit() will set all negative numbers as not numbers.
What other ways are there to check whether a string contains numbers?

Sample input: 1  2 -2 asdf 4.

Comment: Why don't you directly work on `line`, rather than wrapping a string stream round it?

Comment: Have you heard of `std::stoi`, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the leading character is `-` (or `+`, or whatever else you'll accept), and if so, remove it, then use your current test for what remains.

A fuller solution would be to use a regular expression.